# How to apply vertical swipe navigation in the most approachable way?

Tags: android-viewpager, android

I'm trying to implement vertical navigation in my app (full screen fragments that you can swipe up and down). Problem is that there's no possibility to set vertical direction for android ViewPager, so I've used Jake's Wharton DirectionalViewPager that actually works, but I cannot apply pageTransformer to it (it's just not implemented there and that feature implementation fix is too hard for me to do). DirectionalViewPager is no longer supported. So my question is: is a viewpager the best solution for solving that kind of UI problem or maybe I should use another approach which is easier and quite easy to apply? I'm total newbie in android programming (I came here from javascript development) and I need some advice on that. Perhaps someone had similar problem and solved it somehow?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The ViewPager it's actually a relatively new component, sorry for my ignorance but I never used this component, what are you trying to accomplish? Maybe you can use another component... Just trying to understand so I can help more

Comment: hi! thanks for reply. what I want to achieve is actually the same thing as shown here on the GIF examples (but in vertical direction): http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: would be great to hear any suggestion about doing it in a different way. perhaps ScrollView can perform that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something a lot different then that.

The first thing is to have all the component's you want to scroll in your layout.
Something like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/welcome_first_slide"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/welcome_second_slide"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you will implement the method to manage the content on your activity:

```
private void setCurrentSliderItem(int position){
     LinearLayout currentView = null;
     switch (position) {
        case 0:
                mainSlideView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.welcome_first_slide);
                break;
            case 1:
            mainSlideView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.welcome_second_slide);
            break;
     }
     mainSlideView.bringToFront();
     Animation slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f); 
     slide.setDuration(1000);   
     mainSlideView.startAnimation(slide);
}
```

And you will then controle the touch event, so the user can interact:

```
private float xWhenDown;

@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            xWhenDown = event.getX();
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if(event.getX()<xWhenDown){
                buildSlide(++currentPosition);
            }
        default:
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion! I will try this out and then come back to give feedback on that. But I'm afraid that this will be not flexible enough. It can cause some memory problems because of many pages (this is very possible scenario). ViewPager eg. destroys pages when they are out of the screen to manage memory efficiently.

Comment: You can do all inflation inside your activity class, then you don't need to set the content on the XML... The content was put on XML in my answer to simplify the code :P

Answer (score 0):

you can use viewPager2 that supported vertically view pager just set orientation

```
    `<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
           android:id="@+id/view_pager"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           android:orientation="vertical"/>`
```